# GridBagLayout with multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to create a `JFrame` consisting of multiple panels in it. However I want to have two separate panels, one for buttons, and the other for the text. I created the two but now I am trying to use the `GridBagLayout` to organize them into the `JFrame` the way I want them to be. The problem is the text panel will not move to the `gridx,gridy` I placed it at.

```
package gameTest;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
public class SpaceBattle 
{
public int turnCount = 1;
public int buttonCount = 0;
public JFrame bFrame = new JFrame("Space Battle");
public SpaceBattle(ArrayList<Integer> pStats,ArrayList<Integer> eStats)
{       


    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel,c);

    bFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    bFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel turnNum = new JLabel("Turn " + turnCount);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    mainPanel.add(turnNum,c);
    turnNum.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 24));

    bFrame.setSize(800,400);
    bFrame.setVisible(true);

    JButton attackButton = new JButton("Attack");
    JLabel atkText = new JLabel();
    JLabel dfsText = new JLabel();

    JButton fleeButton = new JButton("Flee");
    JLabel fleeText = new JLabel("You get out by the skin of your teeth.");

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    bFrame.setLocation(dim.width/2-bFrame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-bFrame.getSize().height/2);
    attackButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(eStats.get(2) > 0)
            {

                turnCount++;
                turnNum.setText("Turn " + turnCount);

                //This greatly improves readability of the code
                double tempShieldAbsorb = (double)eStats.get(0);
                double tempShieldDurability = (double)eStats.get(1);
                double tempArmor = (double)eStats.get(2);
                double tempAttack = (double)pStats.get(3);
                double tempAccuracy = (double)pStats.get(4);
                double tempMaxShields = (double)eStats.get(5);

                double tempDmg = tempAttack * (tempAccuracy / 100); //takes the player's dmg and accuracy to determine how much damage it deals per turn.
                double tempArmorNegationPercent = (double)(100/(100+tempArmor));


                if(tempShieldDurability > 0) //makes sure the shields are up
                {
                    if(tempShieldAbsorb < tempDmg) //checks to see if the damage is greater than the shields can take
                    {
                        tempArmor -= (tempDmg - tempShieldAbsorb) * tempArmorNegationPercent; 
                        tempShieldDurability -= tempShieldAbsorb; //if the damage is greater than the shields absorbtion, the shields durability will be hit a max of the shields absorbtion, the rest goes to the armor
                    }                       
                    else if(tempShieldAbsorb>=tempDmg) //if the damage is less than the shields can take, the shield's durability will be hit by the damage
                    {
                        tempShieldDurability -= tempDmg;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tempArmor = tempArmor - (tempDmg * tempArmorNegationPercent); //if there is no more durability on the shields, the armor is hit harder
                }                                       

                tempShieldDurability = Math.round(tempShieldDurability);

                if(tempShieldDurability < 0) //If the tempShields is ever negative it will set it to 0.
                {
                    tempShieldDurability = 0;
                    eStats.set(1, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    eStats.set(1, (int)tempShieldDurability);
                }
                if(tempArmor < 0) //if the tempArmor is ever negative it will set it to 0.
                {
                    eStats.set(2, 0);
                    tempArmor = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    eStats.set(2, (int)tempArmor);
                }

                double shieldPercent = (tempShieldDurability/tempMaxShields) * 100;
                if(shieldPercent < 0) //if the shield percentage ever goes negative this will instantly set the shield percent to 0.
                {
                    shieldPercent = 0;
                }
                if(tempArmor<=0)
                {
                    atkText.setText("You've won the battle!");
                    buttonPanel.setVisible(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    atkText.setText("Enemy Armor: " + Math.round(tempArmor) + " \n" + "Enemy Shields: " + Math.round(shieldPercent) + "%");
                }
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                textPanel.add(atkText,c);
                bFrame.setVisible(true);                            
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Finished battle. You don't need to attack.");
                atkText.setText("You've won the battle.");
            }

            if(pStats.get(2) > 0)
            {
                double shieldAbsorb = (double)pStats.get(0);
                double shieldDurability = (double)pStats.get(1);
                double armor = (double)pStats.get(2);
                double attack = (double)eStats.get(3);
                double accuracy = (double)eStats.get(4);
                double maxShields = (double)pStats.get(5);

                double dmg = attack * (accuracy / 100); //takes the player's dmg and accuracy to determine how much damage it deals per turn.
                double armorNegationPercent = (double)(100/(100+armor));


                if(shieldDurability > 0) //makes sure the shields are up
                {
                    if(shieldAbsorb < dmg) //checks to see if the damage is greater than the shields can take
                    {
                        armor -= (dmg - shieldAbsorb) * armorNegationPercent; 
                        shieldDurability -= shieldAbsorb; //if the damage is greater than the shields absorbtion, the shields durability will be hit a max of the shields absorbtion, the rest goes to the armor
                    }                       
                    else if(shieldAbsorb>=dmg) //if the damage is less than the shields can take, the shield's durability will be hit by the damage
                    {
                        shieldDurability -= dmg;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    armor = armor - (dmg * armorNegationPercent); //if there is no more durability on the shields, the armor is hit harder
                }                                       

                shieldDurability = Math.round(shieldDurability);

                if(shieldDurability < 0) //If the tempShields is ever negative it will set it to 0.
                {
                    shieldDurability = 0;
                    pStats.set(1, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    pStats.set(1, (int)shieldDurability);
                }
                if(armor < 0) //if the tempArmor is ever negative it will set it to 0.
                {
                    pStats.set(2, 0);
                    armor = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    pStats.set(2, (int)armor);
                }

                double pShieldPercent = (shieldDurability/maxShields) * 100;
                if(pShieldPercent < 0) //if the shield percentage ever goes negative this will instantly set the shield percent to 0.
                {
                    pShieldPercent = 0;
                }
                if(armor<=0)
                {
                    dfsText.setText("You've lost this one!");
                    buttonPanel.setVisible(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    dfsText.setText("Ship Armor: " + Math.round(armor) + " \n" + "Shields: " + Math.round(pShieldPercent) + "%");
                }
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 1;
                textPanel.add(dfsText,c);
                bFrame.setVisible(true);                            
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Finished battle. You don't need to attack.");

            }
        }

    });

    fleeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            c.gridx = 3;
            c.gridy = 3;
            textPanel.add(fleeText,c);
        }
    });
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    buttonPanel.add(attackButton,c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(fleeButton,c);
    bFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    bFrame.getContentPane().add(textPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    bFrame.setVisible(false);
}
}
```

Comment: Your `textPanel` is not using a `GridBagLayout` layout but you seem to use a `GridBagConstraints` object when you add components to it.

Comment: The same goes for the `buttonPanel` `JPanel`.